# Unable to load app which has been side loaded onto android device using an Intent URL

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-intent, progressive-web-apps

I have two android applications. One is a progressive web app (PWA) and the other is react native (RN). The react native app is side loaded onto the device, through transferring & installing an APK via a cable - it is not installed from the google play store.

I am trying to load the RN app from a button on the PWA. I have been able to load the RN app from a separate RN app using the node package: 'react-native-send-intent' https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-send-intent

However, the PWA cannot use the same node package and must use an Intent URL, similar to the one below:

```
const myIntent = intent://#Intent;action=${myAction};type=${myType};package=${myPackage};S.extra=${myExtra};end

window.location.href = myIntent
```

These are the intent filters that are in the RN AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/json"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

The Intent URL is not opening the RN app. The page is redirected to the google play store and we get a 'Something went wrong' message. The app should be directly loaded form the intent.

Is there a way to open the RN app from the PWA?

Thanks!

Comment: `const myIntent = intent://#Intent;action=${myAction};type=${myType};package=${myPackage};S.extra=${myExtra};end` Please tell how your string would look like when all is filled in. We cannot even see if you use VIEW or SEND.

Comment: Hi blackapps, thanks for getting back to me.
The string would look something like this:
`intent://#Intent;action='android.intent.action.SEND';type='application/json';package='BUNDLE_ID';S.extra='JSON.stringify({token: TOKEN})';end`




I have also tried a shorter string which looks like this:
```let action = 'android.intent.action.SEND';
   let type = 'text/plain';
   let intent = `intent://open/#Intent;action=${action};package='BUNDLE_ID';end`;
```

Comment: You did not fill in the package name as 'BUNDLE_ID' ??? What would that be,?

Comment: I'd rather not share that information if possible. The app is not available on the app store & not publicly available, id prefer to keep it that way for data security reasons.

I can say that we have been able to launch youtube using 'com.google.android.youtube' as the BUNDLE_ID/package with the shorter intent URL, but that just takes me to the app in the google play store rather than actually opening the app.

Comment: You can use a fake package name like com.bbb.ccc. What you do now is unreadable. And the play store has nothing to do with it.. But... test with an app that is not -yet- in the play store.